# "Application priority" in Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop 2.9.0. Is it possible to submit jobs with different priorities in YARN? According to some JIRA tickets it seems that application priorities have now been implemented.

I tried using the `YarnClient`, and setting a priority to the `ApplicationSubmissionContext` before submitting the job. I also tried using the CLI and using `updateApplicationPriority`. However, nothing seems to be changing the application priority, it always remains 0.

Have I misunderstood the concept of ApplicationPriority for YARN? I saw some documentation about setting priorities to queues, but for my use case I need all jobs in one queue.

Will appreciate any clarification on my understanding, or suggestions about what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to set priority of your applications on the yarn cluster.

**Leaf Queue-level priority**
You can define queues with different priority and use spark-submit to submit your application to the specific queue with the wanted priority.

Basically you can define your queues in etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml like this:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.prod.queues</name>
  <value>prod1,prod2</value>
  <description>Production queues.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.test.queues</name>
  <value>test1,test2</value>
  <description>Test queues.</description>
</property>
```

See documentation of queue properties [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Queue_Properties)

> Note: Application priority works only along with FIFO ordering policy.
>   Default ordering policy is FIFO.

In order to set application priority you can add properties like this to the same file:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.test.default-application-priority</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>Test queues have low priority.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.prod.default-application-priority</name>
  <value>90</value>
  <description>Production queues have high priority.</description>
</property>
```

See more information about application priority [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setup_for_application_priority.)

**Changing application priority at runtime:**
If you want to change application priority at runtime you can also use the CLI like this:

```
yarn application -appId <ApplicationId> -updatePriority <Priority>
```

Can you share what command you execute on what node and what response you get?

See more info [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application)

**Using YarnClient**
You did not share your code so it is difficult to see if you do it right. But it is possible to submit a new application with a specific priority using YarnClient

```
ApplicationClientProtocol.submitApplication(SubmitApplicationRequest)
```

See more info [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/protocolrecords/SubmitApplicationRequest.html)

Comment: My usecase won't work with multiple queues. I wanted jobs of different priorities in the _same_ queue. I tried everything that you wrote about, but it doesn't work for me, I guess mainly because I need everything in one queue. I don't think YARN supports that, so wrote an external workaround for the same. Thanks for your help nevertheless.