# Application level priority for Jobs running on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How to add application level priority for Jobs running on YARN. Usecase is to submit applications (both hadoop and spark ) and to set application level priority within one single queue.

Referred to [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setup_for_application_priority.) but couldn't find the config which could control the priority of applications within same queue.

PS : I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673972/application-priority-in-yarn) question, it doesn't solve my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that we can do this by the property -

```
 mapred.job.priority=JobPriority.VERY_HIGH
```

Here you can set it to priority levels available, which are :

```
VERY_HIGH,
HIGH,
NORMAL,
LOW,
VERY_LOW,
DEFAULT
```

Comment: Note that it was not implemented in YARN until 2.8 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1963

Comment: @Neha Kumari, I’m also trying to set priority but Application Priority is still showing 0 when I check yarn status. I set this variable in oozie client properties mapreduce.job.priority=JobPriority.VERY_HIGH. Can you pls share where you set this property?

Answer (score -1):

I think u can't set application level priority in a cluster in a single queue in yarn . You have to create multiple queue for the different application and run.